# identifying points in a simple polygon from a given point

Tags: c, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm, x11

I have a polygon given in the image , I am using x windows programming work on my requirement.

Comment: Iterate over all vertices, for each one calculate the line segment, and see if it intersects any edges?

Comment: How to find whether those two lines intersects?

Comment: Solve the equations representing the two lines for a solution. Simultaneous equations. If they have a solution in real numbers (for 2-D graphs), they intersect, else they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming a 2 dimensional geometry.

For each vertex, you have it's co-ordinates (x, y).
You also have the cor-ordinates for the point selected by the user (X, Y).

From co-ordinate geometry, given two points on a line, you can always find an equation representing the line passing through those two points.

Get the equations of the lines passing through the user selected point (X, Y) and the vertices.

i.e If you have a pentagon, 5 vertices with co-ordinates (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4), (x5, y5) and the co-ordinate of the user selected point is (X, Y), find the equations of the lines passing through...

```
(x1, y1) and (X, Y) --> L1
(x2, y2) and (X, Y) --> L2
(x3, y3) and (X, Y) --> L3
(x4, y4) and (X, Y) --> L4
(x5, y5) and (X, Y) --> L5
```

Next, Find the equations for the edges in the same manner as stated above..

```
(x1, y1) and (x2, y2) --> E1
(x2, y2) and (x3, y3) --> E2
(x3, y3) and (x4, y4) --> E3
(x4, y4) and (x5, y5) --> E4
(x5, y5) and (x1, y1) --> E5
```

Now, take L1 and solve this with E1, E2, E3, E4 and E5. If there is a solution for at least one combination, then do not select the point. Else select it.

Repeat this process for each L and you will have your vertices.

There are tons of links on the internet to find the equation of a line passing through two points.

Comment: This is helpful .How to determine if two line segments intersect.I searched about this but i mostly found intersection of two lines and not line segments. Any help ?

Comment: @Rdvsm Just solve the two equations representing the lines for a solution. Simultaneous equations in algebra.